# BUILD FAILED in 1s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\mouaz\OneDrive\Documents\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 950
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'.
> > Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Just downloaded flutter, but it doesn't work.
When I connect an emulator, this erorr happens.
Please HELP :(

This is what appeared when I runned flutter doctor -v:

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.12, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702], locale ar-EG)
• Flutter version 3.7.12 on channel stable at C:\Users\mouaz\OneDrive\Documents\Flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 4d9e56e694 (3 weeks ago), 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
• Engine revision 1a65d409c7
• Dart version 2.19.6
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\mouaz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
• Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.1+9-29)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.5)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33627.172
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.78.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\mouaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.62.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.140
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.35

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Comment: Please run flutter doctor -v in your terminal & post the output here

Comment: I've runned flutter doctor -v and edited my post.